# How to fetch records in batches in rails for a specific condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datecreated

I am writing a rake task, to populate a "Product" object records. my current logic is

```
namespace :populate_product do
    desc "This task is to populate product object, with product ID"
        task populate_coaching_product_id: :environment do
        UserProduct.find_each(batch_size: 10_000) do |user_product|
          user_product.save
        end
    end
end
```

Now in the above query, I want to fetch records which are created 90 days back, from now. How can I change the above query?

Comment: You mean exactly 90 days back? Or at most 90 days back? Or at least 90 days back?

Comment: exactly 90 days back.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Ref [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches)

Something like

```
 Person.where("age > 21").find_in_batches do |group|
   sleep(50) # Make sure it doesn't get too crowded in there!
   group.each { |person| person.party_all_night! }
 end
```

For the records which are created 90 days back use

```
UserProduct.where('created_at <= ?', Time.now - 90.days ).find_each(batch_size: 10000) do |user_product|
  user_product.save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
UserProduct.where('created_at >= ?', Time.now - 90.days ).find_each(batch_size: 10_000) do |user_product|
  user_product.save
end
```

Note: If you don't care about hour & minute, you can use:

```
Date.today - 90.days
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is it less than or equal to or greater than or equal to? because i am getting all the records.

Comment: Sorry, Its my mistake. I edited answer to `created_at` greater than or equal to 90 days back from now.